# Authentication from C# to MySQL CakePhp users

Tags: c#, cakephp

I'm currently migrating a CakePhp app to ASP.NET. One thing that is blocking me at this point is that I'm unable to get the right hashing method to get the right password fit so users are able to sign-in from the ASP.NET app.

I have the salt value that is set in config/core.php file.

I've googled to try to determined where to find which hashing algorithm is used, and was not able to find the right query or no result.

here is my C# method so far to hash the password.

```
public static string ToHash(this string password, string salt)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    return "";

  var provider = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
  var encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
  var bytes = provider.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(salt + password));
  return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
}
```

I've tried to put the salt before or after the password, it's currently no matching at all, here is the hash password from the cakephp mysql database:

c7fb60ef77dbe3d1681a68e6741ee3a23cc1f41d

Here is what I have from my method

��3[v"���1�:�ѐ��

Not really sure where/how to solve this problem. Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have it!

At least it works for my configuration:

Find salt from `Core.php` (search for `Security.salt` in the file). Then, use this code (very similar to the question):

```
string input = textBox1.Text;
input = "your salt should be here" + input;
var provider = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
var bytes = provider.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(input));
sha1result.Text = Bin2Hex(bytes);
```

Helper for Bin2Hex is also here:

```
public static string Bin2Hex(byte[] ba)
{
    string hex = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
    return hex.Replace("-", "");
}
```

It wasn't easy finding it, I searched through some of internet (no results!) and finally resorted to source-digging.

Comment: After this success, we went even further - allowed authenticated users from cake to automatically be recognized and logged-in on other side - asp.net.  I'll share this if someone would be kind to ask a question :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't have the Cake sources with me right now, but you should easily be able to look up Cake's hashing and salting method in the source.

The above differences in data look like Cake transforms the hash bytes into a string with the hash's bytes in hex base. Whatever the difference in the hash method, you'll have to convert the C# hash's result into such a string as well before comparing them (or go the other way and parse Cake's hex string and build a byte array out of it).